# select with type to search and images (html)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a select with a list of coins and ready-made images with a "type to search" method, exactly as it is in the images. After several searches on the internet I can't find anything that gives me the same result as the image.

Does anyone know how to do this with HTML, CSS and JS??

1.[select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSgLx.png)

2. [when the user clicks on select it shows the option of "type to seach"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhvt2.png)
3. [when the user starts typing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFvNi.png)

Comment: Are you looking for a JavaScript library that allows you to do that, or trying to figure out the code yourself? The pattern is mostly called *Autosuggest*, and you will find plenty of libraries already available, the most used being probably [typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/). Beware, though, that there is plenty of aspects to consider to do it well, for example keyboard control, positioning on top or bottom depending on scroll position. See also the [Combobox Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/) for some accessibility aspects.

Comment: I've already managed to make the suggestion method with select2, and my main question is how to create an input for the user to search for a new currency whenever he clicks on select (as shown in image 2).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I didn't put my code because I want to do something new, so I just put the idea and images of what I want to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is the following solution :

```
<input id="searchCountries" list="countries" placeholder="type to search">
<datalist id="countries">
   <option value="&#127467&#127479 FRANCE">
   <option value="&#127464&#127475 CHINA">
   <option value="&#127482&#127480 USA">
   <option value="&#127466&#127480 SPAIN">
   <option value="&#127463&#127479 BRAZIL">
</datalist>
```

With a little bit of CSS it should exactly do what you want.

And if you want there's a lot of library that can do this.